# Ubuntu 14.04 - Blocked after suspending

Tags: 14.04, suspend

I've updated my **Sony Vaio PCG-3C1M** to **Ubuntu 14.04** and since then I have this issue, when the laptop goes for suspension, usually when the screen is closed, the laptop can't "wake up" after that.

After the screen is closed if you open it again it is blocked, without the login/password screen, and after 40 secs or so, it goes to black screen and I have to restart the laptop.

- Does anyone knows the solution for this ?

Comment: See the debugging section for some hints: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend  1st one: "try suspend without restricted devices (nvidia, fglrx)". also noteworthy "after the failure, on reboot, examine the dmesg output for "device hash" entries to track down the device that hung the system during resume. "

Comment: I've read the wiki but I'm not sure where should I change the values to suspend without restricted devices

Comment: "restricted devices" is the official term for the 3rd party drivers (we tend to install the driver for the videocard driver in additional hardware).  Remove those and test suspend.